# Wordpress multisite, allow non super admins to create sites

Tags: multisite, admin, user-roles, multisite-user-management

I'm creating a wordpress multisite for at costumer to uses with his own customers. He need to be able to create a site when he get a new customer, and his customer should be able to control the the site.

So I want me as an superadmin, and my customer's customers to be the admin the site, so what I need is a role in between a light version of the superadmin.

I can't figure this out, i have tried different plugins fx: "User Role Editor", but no luck so fare.

Someone now how to make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I finally found the solution.
If installed the: "[Extended Super Admins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/extended-super-admins/)" plugin.

And then I the user the Super Admin role, and used the plugin to add a custom role based on the super admin and then it is just check the boxed of the rights he **DON'T** need to have.

It was really that simple!

Answer (score 2):

In multisite installation there already is a default admin and [super-admin role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin), and if standard capabilities are different than what you want you can modify them:

> A default set of capabilities is pre-assigned to each role, but other capabilites can be assigned or removed using the `add_cap()` and `remove_cap()` functions. New roles can be introduced or removed using the `add_role()` and `remove_role()` functions.

In this way you can customize user capabilities to your needs;

---

As asked from toscho I'll make an example:

you can specify new role and caps with `add_role()` (in ex. `maior-admin`)

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','maior_add_role_function');

function maior_add_role_function(){
$roles_set = get_option('my_roles_are_set');
if(!$roles_set){
    add_role(
'maior-admin',
'mj admin',
 array(
    'manage_sites' => true,
    'read'         => true,  
    'edit_posts'   => true,
    //set all capabilities needed - you could do this with get_role() but not so straightforward
)
);
    update_option('my_roles_are_set',true);
}
}
```